# How to use the length of every RouteConfig in id parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been searched some possible solution but i came up to this:

Here's my sample Code from View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GetSig", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "2" }))
 {

 }
```

And here's my RouteConfig.cs

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetSig",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetSig", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

as we observed `id` has been set to `2` but when i run the the code there's no id or length added to the actual url and it will look like this

```
http://localhost:6387/Home/GetSig
```

What am i expecting is it added into the actual url like

```
http://localhost:6387/Home/GetSig?Lenght=2
```

Is it possible to achive this issue? my goal is wherever the user working on the current page. If the user working below then after the execution has been done then the page always display the location of the screen which below the page. That is why i'm hoping that using length or id in the `url` can solved this problem.

Any idea is appreciated..

Comment: You adding an `id` attribute, not a route value (you using the wrong overload of `Html.BeginForm()`)

Comment: Thanks i know it is working in ActionLink but what am i trying to do is in at  BeginForm beacuse i need an image using this `multipart/form-data`

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSig", "Home", new { id = 2 }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` - you want [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29)

Comment: But your question is a bit confusing, and I'm guessing that you really want a bookmark?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @StephenMUecke no i'm not.. Im just trying to achive this issue whatever it takes any any solution would be made.

Comment: I need to try your sample Code from above.. thanks a lot.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks but it will add only an id to the url like `http://localhost:6487/Home/GetSig/2` is it possible to take the length like 'ActionLink' do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154733/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-reds).